# Converting JOIN to Subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery, in-subquery

I am trying to figure out how to convert a JOIN to a subquery. I am using AdventureWorks2019 database and I am pulling data from two tables. My JOIN statement I created is:

```
SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, StateProvinceID
FROM Person.Person AS P
  JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS BEA
    ON P.BusinessEntityID = BEA.AddressID
  JOIN Person.Address AS A
    ON BEA.BusinessEntityID = A.AddressID
WHERE StateProvinceID = 79;
```

How do I turn this into a subquery? Do I create them in FROM or WHERE?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: What would that even mean "Converting a join to a subquery"? Joins and subqueries are not mutually exclusive.